# Turn off Azure function host polling to terminal

Tags: c#, azure-functions

I'm debugging an Azure function in vs code using the azure functions extension. How can I stop the host from writing to console after every single storage queue poll?

[image]

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551) Aside from that: note that queue-polling implements exponential backoff when there's no data, so you won't always see constant logging.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you can solve this by modifying your logging `logLevel` in your `host.json` file.

If I'm not mistaken, the category for `Storage Queue Polling` should be: `Azure.Core` or possibly `Azure.Core1`. You might want to play around with these settings.

For example:

```
 {
  "version": "2.0",
  "functionTimeout": "00:10:00",
  "logging": {
    "logLevel": {
      "default": "Information",
      "Azure.Core": "Warning",
      "Azure.Core1": "Warning"
    },
    "applicationInsights": {
      "samplingSettings": {
        "isEnabled": false
      }
    }
  }
}
```